# Dot notation in pandas/json

Tags: python, json, pandas, notation

Can somebody explain me why I cannot access a pandas dataframe created from json with a dot notation. Or at least, not if the dataframe is not too nested.

If my json file consists of:

```
{
  "mass":{
    "e": 0.511,
    "mu": 105.758,
    "pi0": 134.977,
    "pi+": 139.570,
    "k0": 497.648,
    "k+": 493.667
  }
}
```

I can perfectly do:

```
glob = pd.read_json('Constants/constants.json')
print glob.mass.e
```

However, if my json file looks like this:

```
{
  "physics":{
    "mass":{
      "e": 0.511,
      "mu": 105.758,
      "pi0": 134.977,
      "pi+": 139.570,
      "k0": 497.648,
      "k+": 493.667
    },
    "ckm":{
      "ud": 0.97427,
      "us": 0.22534
    }
  },
  "experiment":{
    "detector":{
      "width": 2.56,
      "height": 2.33,
      "length": 10.37,
      "distance": 470
    },
    "decayPipe":{
      "length": 50
    }
  }
}
```

Then, doing:

```
glob = pd.read_json('Constants/constants.json')
print glob.physics.mass.e
```

will return

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance mass is a Series which creates properties for each of the items under it. It does not repeat this process n levels deep so in the second instance mass is just a dict which you need to use bracket notation to access.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there anyway to keep the dot notation n levels deep?

Comment: There isn't an easy way built-in AFAIK but you could do it yourself. As a basic idea you can write gl.physics.mass = pd.Series(gl.physics.mass). To be more generic you could loop through the first Series, checking for dictionaries and then converting them to Series, though this would be getting away from what a Series is usually used to represent, which is a 1-dimensional "column" of data.